# Tabstop in jVi (NetBeans)

Tags: netbeans

I find the default value (8) for tabstop is too much, so I tried to :set ts=4, but it doesnt work for me. :set all show the tabstop=4 value, but when I close a tab and open it again, ts is reset to be 8.
How can I change the default ts value?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `jVi` is similar to `vi` or `vim` there is a `.vimrc` file that contains defaults. The `:set ts=4` command is temporary, to make it permanent you'll have to either add it to jVi's equivalent `.vimrc` file or if `jVi` is like `vi` and/or `vim` then it can allow you to embed the `set` commands right into the text file as comments. This feature is called **modelines**.

**For example:**

```
// vim: noai:ts=4:sw=4
```

or like this:

```
# vim: ts=4
```

They need to be within the last 5 lines of the file (this is configurable in vi/vim too).

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic

I realize this is `Netbeans` editor `jVi` but I'm guessing that it shares a lot of the same features as vi/vim.

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

```
Tools > Options > jVi Config > Buffer Modifications > 'tabstop' 'ts'
```

and set the value to 4 there.

From [the manual](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/ReadmeNetBeans.html):

> The options **shiftwidth**, **expandtabs** and **tabstop** are per file options, so that any editor clones of a given file have the same value for these options. Different files can have different values for these options. The values set through the UI, in the Buffer Modification tab of the jViConfig options are the default values when a file is opened; setting the values in the UI is like putting them in a .vimrc